# Disable default option key binding

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, emacs

In any text editor, when I type
<kbd>⌥ p</kbd> it inserts `π` at cursor
<kbd>⌥ w</kbd> it inserts `∑` at cursor
Thus every key when pressed with option <kbd>⌥</kbd>  inserts some special character.

### Question

How can I disable this ?

### Why I want to disable this?

1. I hardly use these symbols
2. I am an hardcore emacs user, hence I always prefer shortcuts like

   - <kbd>^ A</kbd> to move cursor to beginning, instead of <kbd>Home</kbd>
   - <kbd>^ n</kbd> to next line, instead of <kbd>↓</kbd>
   - <kbd>^ K</kbd> to kill line
     Thus I always use `Control + Key` for every navigation in text.
     But since mac has some other functionaly for `Option + Key` I cannot use some thing like,  <kbd>⌥ w</kbd> to copy region

Note:
- The reason I love Mac over Linux apart from Crispy UI, is its native 
support to emacs shortcuts. If shortcut with `option` modifier work well every text editor will be emacs for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Save the following to `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` (create if necessary).

```
{ "~a" = (); "~b" = (); "~c" = (); "~d" = (); "~e" = (); "~f" = (); "~g" = (); "~h" = (); "~i" = (); "~j" = (); "~k" = (); "~l" = (); "~m" = (); "~n" = (); "~o" = (); "~p" = (); "~q" = (); "~r" = (); "~s" = (); "~t" = (); "~u" = (); "~v" = (); "~w" = (); "~x" = (); "~y" = (); "~z" = (); }
```

This disables all the ⌥<letter> combinations. Restart apps to take effect.

The DefaultKeyBinding.dict above is an old-style property list<sup>1</sup>, defining key-value pairs using the syntax `{ key = value }`. In this case, the keys are the key combinations to activate the method in the value.

Standard dictionary key symbols are used: ~ alt, ^ control, $ shift, @ command.
Therefore `~a` means ⌥A (alt-A) and `^$1` would be ⌃⇧1 (control-shift-1).

The value for each of the keys is set to `()`—empty parentheses without a method. As DefaultKeyBinding.dict overrides `/S*/L*/Fr*/AppKit.*/R*/StandardKeyBinding.dict`, the shortcut is defined to be without method and therefore does nothing. It's preferable to create your own key bindings file like this rather than editing the system one.

<sup><sup>1</sup> Feel free to use a new XML property list style if you prefer—it works the same.</sup>

Comment: I am extremely thankful. It was exactly what I wanted. BTW I would appreciate if you could explain what '~' and `( )` do.

Comment: @Kaunteya Edited answer—does that help?

Comment: Does this work for anyone on MacOs? (Sierra?) No effect for me..

Comment: Is this safe to do in Big Sur (v11.0.1)?

Comment: I tried this out on macOS 12.6 and it did not work, unfortunately

Comment: In 2023, macOS Ventura, this still is the best solution. Be aware, that you first will need to create the folder `mkdir ~/Library/KeyBindings` if it is not there, then write to the file `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`, then reboot the machine.

Comment: This has also just worked beautifully for me on Sonoma 14.1.2. I didn't need to use the curly braces however, my final DefaultKeyBinding.dict is [here](https://github.com/oizik/dotfiles/blob/master/home/private_Library/private_KeyBindings/private_DefaultKeyBinding.dict)

Answer (score 4):

I found that using the `Unicode hex input` input source (`System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources`, then add source and select `Other` under languages) worked for me.
Found this after trying to change input sources based on @exmaxx's suggestion. NOTE: Using ABC (my default) or US did not solve the problem for me.

Comment: this is the best solution IMO. It solves the problem whilst preserving shortcuts in inserting characters like é by simply switching to the ABC input method.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone finding this later and having problems with this.

I was unsuccessful doing this, and the other option with Ukelele has it's own problems (hard to remove default keyboard), so I ended up using BetterTouchTool to replace Option shortcuts with other actions.

Answer (score 1):

The solution also might be to **use different keyboard layout**, e.g. `U.S.`:

- problems with "alt" keys: `U.S. International`, `ABC`
- solution: `U.S.`

Change it in `System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Input Sources`.

---

*I found the solution on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12759063/2016383) so you might give the author a credit if it helped you also ;)*

Comment: didn't work for me though (macOS Monterey 12.6)